# How to use properly centos dockerfile with ubuntu host?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, docker

I would like to know if it is dangerous or dumb to use a centos image with an ubuntu host.
I understand the main concepts with Docker (lxc, aufs...) but if we start a centos container is it a real centos ? the kernel is this from ubuntu. How to deal with it ?

Sorry if my question is bad explained.

Thanks a lot. Best regards
Nicolas

Answer (score 5):

It would be the same as to use Centos with a Ubuntu kernel. Most of things would work, but you could have some side effects(e.g. selinux may stop working because ubuntu supports appamor instead).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder how any processes into CentOS could run without problem with a kernel provided by Ubuntu. It is hard to evaluate problem :) I think I will run only ubuntu images with Ubuntu Host and CentOS into CentOS. Best regards,