# Is it possible and safe running Docker containers with Debian on CenstOS host machine?

Tags: docker

First of all I've read [How to use properly centos dockerfile with ubuntu host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970776/how-to-use-properly-centos-dockerfile-with-ubuntu-host), but it has been asked over a year ago and maybe something changed and also I am asking about Debian image inside CentOS host.

I have app that consists of three docker images:

- Web - node.js app based on https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ which is based on debian image
- PostgreSQL - https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ based on debian image
- Redis.io - https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/ which is based on debian image

Is it possible to run this app on CentOS host? Is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it doesn't matter at all.
Only the kernel needs to be compatible, which is given my the docker host version you need to use ;)

Comment: So let's say I am logged in on CentOS host and I have access to `docker` command. How I can check which kernel version my debian images must have to run on host machine?

Comment: You dont need, look in hub.docker.io for the image description. Normaly there is a mark about which is minimum version of docker to run this image. Or try and error, when your docker host can start the container, everythink is ok. Other wise it will show you an error like, "You have to update your system, because you need docker version x and kernel version y"